# How to unit test module with provider dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have an existing angular app. Now I want to start with some unit tests. I use jasmine and karma to test my services.
My problem is that I am not able to test a service with the $stateProvider dependency. 
What I am using:
- angularjs 1.5.8
- angular mocks 1.5.8

My code:

```
angular.module('starter.start', []).config(function ($stateProvider) {
          // ...
}).factory('MyService', function() {
          // ...
});
```

The test:

```
describe('MyServiceSpec', function() {
    var MyService;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('starter.start'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_MyService_) {
        MyService= _MyService_;
    }));

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(MyService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I get the error `Unknown provider: $stateProvider`.
In my research I found out that I need to do something with `$provide` but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add $stateProvider in your config file

next you need to inject ui.router before your main app

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('starter.start'));
```

and then you need to call service

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But isnt there a way to mock the $stateProvider? In future I dont want to init all dependencies that my module config has as dependency like the $stateProvider. Because the actual service I want to test has nothing to do with the $stateProvider.

Comment: you have to inject the dependency that you will be using for a particular testcase it is not necessary to inject everything  from config.